# apk crashes after Buildozer

Tags: android, kivy, apk, adb, buildozer

I am not able to know why My APK app is crashing
is it a proplem with psutil this is my requirements line
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,psutil,speedtest,pillow
this is my import lines

```
import datetime
import threading
import random
from time import sleep
import psutil
import speedtest
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from get_size import get_size
from get_size_bits import get_size_bits
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem,ThreeLineListItem,MDList
```

and this is the adb log

```
08-11 18:28:41.021 25786 25832 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
08-11 18:28:41.021 25786 25832 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
08-11 18:28:41.022 25786 25832 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by 
ANDROID_ARGUMENT
08-11 18:28:41.022 25786 25832 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app
08-11 18:28:41.022 25786 25832 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
08-11 18:28:41.022 25786 25832 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
08-11 18:28:41.022 25786 25832 I python  : calculated paths to be...
08-11 18:28:41.022 25786 25832 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
08-11 18:28:41.025 25786 25832 I python  : set wchar paths...
08-11 18:28:41.122 25786 25832 I python  : Initialized python
08-11 18:28:41.123 25786 25832 I python  : AND: Init threads
08-11 18:28:41.124 25786 25832 I python  : testing python print redirection
08-11 18:28:41.127 25786 25832 I python  : Android path ['.', 
'/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', 
  '/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', 
'/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
08-11 18:28:41.130 25786 25832 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH':'/sbin:/system/sbin:/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/ 
vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'MOUNT_SYSTEM_OK': 'true', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': 
'/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': 
'/storage', 'ANDROID_RUNTIME_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.runtime', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': 
'/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 
'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core- 
 oj.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/smartbondingservice.jar:/system/framework/securetimersdk.jar:/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar:/system/framework/timakeystore.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_sdk.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_hidden_sdk.jar:/system/framework/drutils.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/system/framework/ucmopensslenginehelper.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/smartbondingservice.jar:/system/framework/securetimersdk.jar:/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar:/system/framework/timakeystore.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_sdk.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_hidden_sdk.jar:/system/framework/drutils.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/system/framework/ucmopensslenginehelper.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar:/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/uibc_java.jar:/system/framework/ssrm.jar', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'SECONDARY_STORAGE': '/storage/sdcard:/storage/usb1:/storage/usb2', 'MC_AUTH_TOKEN_PATH': '/efs', 'KNOX_STORAGE': '/data/knox/ext_sdcard', 'ENC_EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET': '/storage/enc_emulated', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '15', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_primary': '16', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app:/data/user/0/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'True', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'portrait', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
08-11 18:28:41.130 25786 25832 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
08-11 18:28:41.130 25786 25832 I python  : AND: Ran string
08-11 18:28:41.130 25786 25832 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
08-11 18:28:41.376 25786 25832 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
08-11 18:28:41.377 25786 25832 I python  :   File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 5, in <module>
08-11 18:28:41.377 25786 25832 I python  :   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/mykivymdapp/arm64-v8a/psutil/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
08-11 18:28:41.377 25786 25832 I python  :   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/mykivymdapp/arm64-v8a/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 26, in <module>
08-11 18:28:41.377 25786 25832 I python  : ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.mykivymdapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_linux.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
08-11 18:28:41.377 25786 25832 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: Please do not post code in screen shots. Just copy and paste code into your question and format it as code.

Comment: I edited it, do you have the answer ?

Comment: `EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)` means that your app contains `_psutil_linux.so` library only suitable for an emulator (x86). For a real device you need arm64 library. Not sure where you have to specify that in Buildozer.

Comment: may you please explain more

Comment: and what is arm64 ?

Comment: AARCH64=ARM64 is the name of the CPU architecture of your smartphone CPU.

Answer (score 0):

write your code in **try exception** and return the error.
an example:

```
class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
def build(self):
    s = ""
    try:
        print("hello")
        print("write your code here")
    except Exception as ee:
        s += str(ee)
    ss = ""
    #This is to prevent text from running off the page
    for f1 in range(len(s)):
        ss += s[f1]
        if f1 % 10 == 0 and f1 % 9 == 0:
            ss += "\n"
    return Label(text=str(ss))
MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).